# How to make a session exist through out the application in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have set session variable inside the laravel LoginController which was available in the first view i.e. home but was not available in
subsequent views or during refreshing/reloading of the page
i.e.
LoginController

```
session(['loginDate'=>$loginDate]);
session(['nickname'=>$nickName]);
```

home.blade.php

```
{{$loginDate}} this can be seen as well as {{$nickName}}
```

otherviews.blade.php

```
{{$loginDate}} this as been lost as well as this {{$nickName}}
```

Please how can I make the session that i set to be consistent when the sesion is active and also possibly assign it to an id
that can be terminated when the user logs out.

Comment: did you use `{{ Session::get('error')}}` in blade template? or did you set $loginDate to session value before sending in it to blade?

Comment: I do not understand wat u mean. they way I have done is the way I just put it up

Comment: what you set value of `$loginDate` before passing it to `otherviews.blade.php`?

Comment: I set it in the controller through session(['loginDate'=>$loginDate]); then i called through {{$loginDate}}

Comment: that's the point. there is no `$loginDate` variable in other pages cause you named session value `loginDate`. Instead try to use `{{session('loginDate')}}` or `{{Session::get('error')}}`

Comment: Sorry for typo, `{{Session::get('loginDate')}}`

Comment: I will try and get back. Thanks